# sp_xml_preparedocument go with error "Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document"

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, timestamp

I'am trying to execute sp_xml_preparedocument and geting error "Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document"

my T-SQL commands:

```
DECLARE @aa XML
DECLARE @idoc int
SET @aa =(select * from db_name for xml auto, xmldata)
```

---

@aa now is

```
<Schema xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-data" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" name="Schema7">
<ElementType name="Person" content="empty" model="closed">
  <AttributeType name="preson_id" dt:type="i4" />
  <AttributeType name="Name" dt:type="string" />
  <AttributeType name="Surname" dt:type="string" />
  <AttributeType name="guid" dt:type="uuid" />
  <AttributeType name="version" dt:type="bin.base64" />
  <attribute type="preson_id" />
  <attribute type="Name" />
  <attribute type="Surname" />
  <attribute type="guid" />
  <attribute type="version" />
 </ElementType>
</Schema>
  <Person xmlns="x-schema:#Schema7" preson_id="1" Name="Иван" Surname="Иванов" guid="2E739E87-3CA4-4ED8-ADD0-8B59957668B8" version="AAAAAAAAB9E=" />
  <Person xmlns="x-schema:#Schema7" preson_id="2" Name="Николай" Surname="Николаев" guid="BDC41C59-D70F-4B70-954E-4918B9516AF8" version="AAAAAAAAB9I=" />
  <Person xmlns="x-schema:#Schema7" preson_id="3" Name="Максим" Surname="Максимов" guid="740E57F3-56BA-48B8-92AF-978D7B1D2712" version="AAAAAAAAB9M=" />
```

---

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @aa
```

---

```
The XML parse error 0xc00ce555 occurred on line number 1, near the XML text ""
Msg 6602, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_xml_preparedocument, Line 1
The error description is 'Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document
```

---

I'am new in this, and i need help)))
An one more question - How parse timestamp type?

if i use

```
SET @aa =(select * from db_name for xml elements, root('root'), type)
```

sp_xml_preparedocument works fine, OPENXML returns all values of my db_table, but timestamp values looks not the same as were..

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Put the second part re timestamp as a separate question as it requires a different answer

Answer (score 0):

SELECT @aa returns

```
<Schema xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-data" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" name="Schema7">
<ElementType name="Person" content="empty" model="closed">
  <AttributeType name="preson_id" dt:type="i4" />
  <AttributeType name="Name" dt:type="string" />
  <AttributeType name="Surname" dt:type="string" />
  <AttributeType name="guid" dt:type="uuid" />
  <AttributeType name="version" dt:type="bin.base64" />
  <attribute type="preson_id" />
  <attribute type="Name" />
  <attribute type="Surname" />
  <attribute type="guid" />
  <attribute type="version" />
 </ElementType>
</Schema>
  <Person xmlns="x-schema:#Schema7" preson_id="1" Name="Иван" Surname="Иванов" guid="2E739E87-3CA4-4ED8-ADD0-8B59957668B8" version="AAAAAAAAB9E=" />
  <Person xmlns="x-schema:#Schema7" preson_id="2" Name="Николай" Surname="Николаев" guid="BDC41C59-D70F-4B70-954E-4918B9516AF8" version="AAAAAAAAB9I=" />
  <Person xmlns="x-schema:#Schema7" preson_id="3" Name="Максим" Surname="Максимов" guid="740E57F3-56BA-48B8-92AF-978D7B1D2712" version="AAAAAAAAB9M=" />
```

Comment: amigo lease add extra information by editing the question not adding answers

Answer (score 0):

An XML document must have one root element only - see [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed).

Thus in you case if Schema is the root element you cannot add the Person elements at the end

Comment: I need to return all data, including timestamp.. Maybe you have some thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is no duplicate entries for the record that you are trying to get

Comment: This is more comment rather than an actual answer